# Django humanize intword remove number round

Tags: django

Currently i'm using **intword** in django to output the price field(**bigint**) like so :

> {{ property.price| intword }}

But i have problem with the precision of the round function of intword

For example if the data is 1490000000 then it should output 1.490 billion but instead it output 1.5 billion . Since this a price data i don't want that much rounding, is there a way to disable rounding or maybe only round till the third fourth number in the  **intword** function from django. If there no options then i guess i have to go basic convert with diversion way.

Comment: intword automatically rounds values to 1 decimal place. I think your best bet is to create your own templatetage base on [intword](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/humanize/templatetags/humanize.py)